# Having difficulty stripping HTML tags from an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a very simple web application that I am having some trouble with. I have two files.

helloWorld.jsp:

```
int result = 0;
out.println("<html><body>"+result+"</body></html>");
```

getHelloWorld.jsp:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript>
 function getHelloWorld() {
                $.get("/helloWorld.jsp, function(data) {

                    var temp = $.trim(data);
                    temp = temp.text(); //have also tried temp.html() and a few other things
                    $('#status').val(temp);

                });
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                getHelloWorld();
            };

</script></head>
<body><div id='status'></div></body></html>
```

My problem is this: When I load getHelloWorld.jsp, I either get nothing (the code above produces no output), or I get "0" printed out. The result that I am trying to achieve is to have just "0" printed out without HTML tags. I cannot use a simple find and replace solution because I need this simple code to work with a much more complicated response. I suppose I could do regex but I would rather not reinvent the wheel if there is already a function to handle this.

Is there any (simple) way to strip the HTML tags from an AJAX call, as above?

Comment: step back and look at the bigger picture: once you get your ajax response, it's just a string. coming from ajax doesn't make it special. You should be asking how to strip html from a string in java.

Comment: And note that it would probably be *much, much easier* to figure out how to avoid embedding your information in HTML in the first place.

Comment: JSP is actually really useful as a JSON-building template system. It doesn't care whether it's generating HTML or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the HTML and put it into a jQuery object (which will cause jQuery to put it into a document fragment and parse the HTML), then extract the text from the jQuery object:

```
       function getHelloWorld() {
            $.get("/helloWorld.jsp", function(data) {

                var temp = $(data).text();
                $('#status').val(temp);

            });
        }
        window.onload = getHelloWorld;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9hxrqgzn/

---

One might wonder why you're returning HTML from your server if you just want a number.  Perhaps you should be returning JSON instead that is just the number and then jQuery will process the JSON response for you and give you just the number you want.

Comment: Here I am returning 0 only because this is a simple example I am trying to get working before moving to a more complicated version. This answer was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSP it's better to include jsp page in this way (on server side):

```
<body>
    <div id='status'>
        <jsp:include page="helloWorld.jsp"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want to use JS try this:

```
        $.get("/helloWorld.jsp", function(data) 
        {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data;
        });
```

But if you want to use JQuery try this:

```
$('#status').load("helloWorld.jsp");
```

When you include like above it strips html and body tags.